# What is the optimal way to do this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object, and i want to convert into other object.

```
var input = [
   { "type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand":"P", "size": "10"},
   {"type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand":"P", "size": "12"},
   {"type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand":"Q", "size": "12"},
   {"type": "Pant", "brand": "B", "subBrand":"P", "size": "10"},
   {"type": "Shirt", "brand": "A", "subBrand":"P", "size": "10"}
];
```

output should be in this format :

```
output = {
    "Pant" : {
       "A" : {
          "P" : {
            "size" : [10,12]
          },
          "Q" : {
           "size" : [12]
          }
       }
       "B" : {
          "P" : {
            "size" : [10]
          }
       }
     },
     "Shirt" : {
        "A" : {
          "P" : {
            "size" : [10]
          }
       }
     }
};
```

I tried to write code and its becoming very complex, each time to check each thing whether its come earlier or not.
Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and build the object you need with a default empty object.

```js
var input = [{ "type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "P", "size": "10" }, { "type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "P", "size": "12" }, { "type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "Q", "size": "12" }, { "type": "Pant", "brand": "B", "subBrand": "P", "size": "10" }, { "type": "Shirt", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "P", "size": "10" }],
    output = {};

input.forEach(function (a) {
    output[a.type] = output[a.type] || {};
    output[a.type][a.brand] = output[a.type][a.brand] || {};
    output[a.type][a.brand][a.subBrand] = output[a.type][a.brand][a.subBrand] || { size: [] };
    output[a.type][a.brand][a.subBrand].size.push(a.size);
});

console.log(output);
```

If you like it a bit tidy (and in ES6), then you could iterate over the keys for the object with reduce and build the object.

```js
var input = [{ "type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "P", "size": "10" }, { "type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "P", "size": "12" }, { "type": "Pant", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "Q", "size": "12" }, { "type": "Pant", "brand": "B", "subBrand": "P", "size": "10" }, { "type": "Shirt", "brand": "A", "subBrand": "P", "size": "10" }],
    output = {};

input.forEach(function (a) {
    var o = ['type', 'brand', 'subBrand'].reduce((r, k) => r[a[k]] = r[a[k]] || {}, output);
    o.size = o.size || [];
    o.size.push(a.size);
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , reduce was awesome !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce`

```
input.reduce((res,x)=>{
 res[x.type] = res[x.type] || {};
 res[x.type][x.brand] = res[x.type][x.brand] || {}
 res[x.type][x.brand][x.subBrand]= res[x.type][x.brand][x.subBrand] || {size:[]}
 res[x.type][x.brand][x.subBrand].size.push(x.size)
 return res;
},{})
```